# Why are phone calls cylindrical?

Tags: etymology, history, counters

> **何本か**重要な電話をかけ、...
>   He made several important phone calls and ...

Originally part of [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/different-ways-to-say-several-and-why-are-phone-calls-cylindrical) but separated due to *popular?* demand.

Why is the counter 本 used in reference to phone calls?

Comment: If you ever encountered a teenage girl, you would know that phone calls can be very loooong. (This said they can be very flat too.)

Comment: http://leo.aichi-u.ac.jp/~jiten/pdf/word-vol4/01.pdf

Comment: You might need to forget about "cylindrical" for a moment.  本 has much wider usage as a counter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be fair, 本　＝　「細長いもの」is a really popular explanation (note that is does not imply anything about being round, I think that it is an usual extrapolation due to the fact that physical objects that are long and thin are *usually* cylindrical).

But many usages actually go against this explanation, or a least do not fall into that classification. Consider the following examples:

- 子どもたちに三本のゲームを買ってきた。
- 彼は三本の新しい企画に取り組んだ。
- 今年は三本のコンサートに行ったよ。

As you can see, you really need to stretch your mind **really** far to find the thin, long thing here. At least I cannot find them...

I've made some quick research on the topic and there appears to be academical research on that topic (!). [Like this one](http://jhlee.sakura.ne.jp/geo-backup/jcpdf/hamano-lee-kurosio.pdf), where they distinguish 6 clusters of words to which 本 applies to.

(for the case of the phone, the "message" coming from letter thing seems plausible though.)

Comment: Nice find. The paper is way too difficult for me to read, but I managed to decode the summary table on page 86.

Answer (score 2):

Does ***THIS*** answer your question?

[image]
[image]

Seems that there are a number of possible explanations though...

1. Parts of the phone, or the phone itself were cylindrical
2. Voice was transmitted via wires (long and thin)
3. The idea of a "message" where a written letter would be rolled up into a cylinder (letter -> telegraph -> telephone)

Comment: +1 Looks convincing. I'll wait to see if anyone has other thoughts before accepting though.

Comment: えっ、わかんない、、、なんで？

Comment: @Chocolate Well I assumed the reasoning was that the old-style phone has lots of cylindrical components.

Comment: 受話器もスピーカーも筒形でしょ？

Comment: え・・そこ？　**回線**を使ってるからかな？と思ってた・・　電報も「一本」だし。。

Comment: Hmmmm... 一理ありますね。電報にも筒形の部品はあるけどそんなに目立たないから…　回線のことかもしれないね

Comment: 昔の手紙が筒に巻いていて、「手紙→電報→電話」という説もありますね

Comment: Even books used to be cylindrical (volumes of books use 巻), yet (quite paradoxically) -本 is not used to count 本.

Comment: @sazarando One may argue that phones, telegraphs, etc. are machines, and should be counted as such, rather than focus on just one part of it.

Comment: From the point of view of an operator facing a switchboard, the number of calls *is* the number of wires plugged in.