# Why あります instead of です in this sentence?

Tags: nuances, verbs

In the following sentence (from [here](https://nhkeasier.com/2019/03/13/)),

> 北海道札幌市の円山動物園に、ミャンマーから来た３頭の象をみんなに見せるための広い場所と建物ができました。[...] 広さは５０００m²以上**あります**。

I would have expected です instead of あります: 広さ = ５０００m²以上.

Answer (score 4):

> 「広さは５０００m²以上**あります**。」

is a perfectly natural-sounding sentence.

**「あります」 can be replaced by 「です」, but that will change rather drastically the basic grammar (if not the meaning) of the sentence.**

In the original sentence, 「５０００m²以上」 functions adverbially to modify the verb phrase 「あります」.  As discussed [in this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65398/different-ways-to-say-several), number-related phrases can function ***adverbially*** in Japanese.  From my own experience with Japanese-learners, however, they seem to have difficulty getting used to this concept.

It is more natural (or more "originally Japanese") to say:

「リンゴが**むっつ**あります。」 ← 「むっつ」 functions ***adverbially***.

than to say:

「むっつのリンゴがあります。」 ← 「むっつの」 functions ***adjectivally***.

Thus, in the sentence you were thinking of:

> 「広さは５０００m²以上**です**。」

「５０００m²以上」 functions as a ***noun***.

Comment: So this is the difference between 'the surface area is 5000+ m²' and 'there is a surface area of 5000+ m²'?

Comment: I would be very careful to say yes here (in fact, I won't) because in English, it is just impossible to use "5,000+ ㎡" adverbially to modify a verb like "to exist".  In Japanese, it is more than possible and natural-sounding to say 「５０００m²以上ある」 with 「５０００m²以上」 modifying 「ある」.  The difference is explainable but it is not literally translatable.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence there is no difference in meaning between です and あります. But あります sounds politer.