# です vs ありますwhat is the difference between the two? Can they ever be interchangeable?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, usage, verbs

Q: 日本語の授業は毎日ありますか。一日に何時間ですか。
A:  日本語の授業は毎日あります。一日に二時間あります。
I have questions about the difference between “です” and “あります” regarding the above sentences taken from my textbook. Why is that “です” was used in the the question instead of “あります” and how come the answer to the sentence that used “です“ used “あります”?

Comment: I think the copula can sometimes replace verbs: ある seems like a particularly likely word to be replaced.

Comment: Related/Duplicate　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66034/45489

Comment: Note that です is a contraction of であります。